# Subscript out of bonds when applying mjca

Tags: r, subscript

I try to apply the mjca function (multiple correspondence analysis) from the ca package and I type in:

```
mca_adjusted <- mjca(dataframe, supcol = 1, lambda = "adjusted")
```

The supcol function is supposed to include the first column as a supplementary variable. Yet, I get the following error message:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, (offset.b[q] + 1):offset.b[q + 1], (offset.b[q] +  : subscript out of bounds
```

The strange thing is that when I change the dataframe in Excel by copying the first column to column seven or so to then include `supcol = 7`, it works!

Comment: This really seems like a bug. Maybe you could alert the maintainer of it? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ca/index.html